# Undefined symbol A2006 (Simple swapping code)

Tags: assembly

Just started assembly and I don't realise what I am doing wrong with the hexadecimal value store in EAX. Here's the code.

```
; AddTwo.asm - adds two 32-bit integers.


.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.code
main proc
    mov eax,AAh
    mov ebx,55h
    mov ecx,eax        ; Store the value of eax in ecx
    mov eax,ebx        ; Move the value of ebx into eax
    mov ebx,ecx        ; Move the original value of eax (stored in ecx) into ebx


    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

It works flawlessly with decimal, but as soon as I try hex it throws an error.

Furthermore, I would like to know if there is any website to learn assembly. I am referring to my lecture slides and this book (The Intel Microprocessors 8086)

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code so that it is readable. Doing so makes helping you easier. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Can't tell what assembler you're using, though maybe try `0AAh`?  Some assemblers like numbers, even hex numbers, to start with a decimal digit, so here adding a leading `0`.  Yet if you want help with an error message, then quote the error message in its entirety.

Comment: Hi Erik, that worked well. Thanks a lot. I was using VS 22 x32. Also, could you suggest to me some material that i can practice or read to understand Assembly better? Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: This is MASM syntax and you can check the full grammar of that syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-bnf-grammar?view=msvc-170 (a `constant` consists of `digits` with an optional radix override suffix, and `digits` must start with a decimal digit, which can be 0 but it cannot be A)

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to learn.  If x86, its dozens of assemblers and history from16-bit to 64-bit, that would be one thing, and if trying to learn general concepts of assembly, I'd recommend looking at the educational/toy processors like LC-3 or MARIE.  For something realistic but not so convoluted, MIPS or RISC V.

Comment: The x86 tag wiki (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has some links to tutorials and official docs, and manuals for assemblers.

Comment: Thank you so much once again i appreciate your help